# Modulo division of large uint64_t from C to Java

Tags: java, c

So, here is a simple C program that I would like to be able to reproduce in Java:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
int main() {
    uint64_t x = 0xB3E110C4CFF34548;

    printf("%16lX %20ld\n", x, x);
    printf("%16lX %20ld\n", x % 5, x % 5);
}
```

Compile with: `gcc -Wall -std=c11 main.c`. My `gcc --version` is `7.1.1 20170621`

So far, I have tried this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long x = 0xB3E110C4CFF34548L;

        System.out.printf("%16X %20d\n", x, x);
        System.out.printf("%16X %20d\n", x % 5, x % 5);
        System.out.printf(
            "%16X %20d\n", Math.floorMod(x, 5), Math.floorMod(x, 5)
            );
    }
}
```

Compile with: `javac Main.c`, my `javac -version` is `1.8.0_131` and I assume it produces Java 8.

However, as you can see for yourself, the results are different. C executable gives you 2 as modulo, while Java gives you -4 or 1 depending on the modulo you use. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Java doesn't have unsigned numbers (at least not built-in).  Some libraries can let you emulate their behavior.

Comment: Yes, but so far I've been able to get away with the fact that "sign" is just a side-effect of how you interpret two's complement, i.e. the bytes underneath are still the same. Does modulo rely on the sign too much (in some sense)?

Comment: Use an `x` in the range of `long`.  C's `0xB3E110C4CFF34548` is not in `long` range.

Comment: @chux are you referring to the `printf` format? That will only make the letters that represent the bytes lowercase instead of uppercase.

Comment: In C, `0xB3E110C4CFF34548` is the same as `12961659640037459272u`.  That is outside the Java `long` range.

Comment: Multiplication, addition, and subtraction don't care about sign.  Remainder and division do.

Comment: @chux well, it is the same 64 bits in two's complement, so while it is technically outside the `signed` long range, Java 8 knows how to treat those bits as if they were an `unsigned` long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, for me the answer turned out to be `Long.remainderUnsigned` which is a new feature since Java 8:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long x = 0xB3E110C4CFF34548L;

        System.out.printf("%16X %20d\n", x, x);
        System.out.printf("%16X %20d\n", x % 5, x % 5);
        System.out.printf(
            "%16X %20d\n", Math.floorMod(x, 5), Math.floorMod(x, 5)
            );
        System.out.printf("%16X %20d\n", Long.remainderUnsigned(x, 5), Long.remainderUnsigned(x, 5));
    }
}
```